Gaps due to time estimation in a feedback control
I have this issue regarding digital feedback control. The variable that contributes to the error is acquired via a protocol that does not report the timestamp of the data. Unfortunately, the error is also calculated based on the elapsed time. The time is therefore estimated from the system clock when the data changes; the logic runs every 10 seconds, the variable is collected every second (sometimes the variable does not vary so miss a second). Due to the approximate estimation of the data timestamp, the error variable unfortunately shows discontinuities, as shown in the figure. Is there a way to mitigate these effects, perhaps by applying a specific filter that does not compromise the responsiveness of the control? Thank you.


I find the picture hard to interpret in terms of what is "correct" and what is an "artifact". The data clearly has strong jumps but these doesn't seem related to wrong time stamps. Can you show some "good" data as well?

The error is calculated by this: Constant*time_elapsed-variable the time_elapsed is t-t0, the jumps occurs whe you miss a sample in the cycle period of the logic (the variable is sampled every second, the logic of control run every 10 second)
